# Rejects or Accepts?

Tags: sentence-meaning, comparison

In the sentence below, does the speaker rejects nationalism or the idea that nationalism is a kind of atavism?

> Some modern political theorists reject nationalism as a tribal atavism.

Thank you all!

Comment: The speaker's views are not stated or implied. It is not possible from the statement alone to know what the speaker thinks.

Comment: *In principle*, both parsings are possible. Another possibility: - in *theory*, some modern political theorists might be actually *seeking* a "tribal atavism" as a desirable goal. And they might have looked at "nationalism" as a possible implementation thereof, but decided to reject it as unsuitable for their purposes. The syntactic construction is ambiguous, so we must be guided by what's pragmatically ***likely*** to be the intended meaning. In this case, there's no doubt whatsoever that the writer means those theorists reject nationalism ***because** they think it's a "tribal atavism"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica seems to be the answer ... Thaaaaaaaanks...